# Creating a dashboard on the site collection level that show all the latest items from its subsites’ lists

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, configuration, app-part

I have a team site collection inside SP 2013. And this team site has 10 sub-sites of type team site.

Now I want inside the site collection home page to show the latest items for all the subsites’ lists by adding App part of each sub site's list. Now I edit the home page of my site collection and I try adding APP Parts, but seems the subsites and their lists are not available in the menu . and only the direct site collection assets can be added as a web app, as follow:-

[image]

So can anyone advice on this please , on how i can add App Parts for the subsites inside the site collection home page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use one of the following:

- Content Search Web Part
- Search Web Part
- Content Query Web Part

The two search web parts are a bit easier to use as far as customizing the queries as there is a designer you can use.  You can also change their looks.  Content Query Web Part requires some XSLT knowledge to get the most out of it.

You will add the search webpart to the page then edit the properties and you will see a button to change the "Search Query" where you can scope your query to one or more sites and content types.

Microsoft has a few tutorials on configuring these search web parts - like this one:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-0DC16DE1-DBE4-462B-BABB-BF8338C36C9A

Comment: i tried adding a Search web Part before , but it provide a poor user interface compared to the App parts. so is there a way to modify those web parts to have better look and feel ?

Comment: You can select different Search Display Teamplates in the search results web parts to give a different look and feel. If you are familiar with HTML/JavaScript you can also create your own, or find some on google that have been created by others

Comment: @StevenMulkerrins but none of the built-in display templates will give the same look and feel compared to using App parts ..second point on do you know if using this approach http://blog.cloudbusiness.com/the-company/blog-and-news/displaying-sharepoint-online-2013-lists-to-parent-or-sub-sites and valid approach in my case ?

Comment: @jesus but will using web parts allow me to create a list on the site collection level that contain the related items from the sub sites? for example let say i have an  issue tracking list named "ListA" which exists inside all the subsites ,, so can i using web parts to retrieve all the "ListA" items from all the subsites that are assign to the login user and display them on one list inside the site collection ?

Answer (score 1):

Only own lists and libraries are available in **APP Part**. You can not add list/library as APP part from other site. The good thing is there are workarounds for this. Check the below link

[Displaying SharePoint Online 2013 lists to parent or sub-sites](http://blog.cloudbusiness.com/the-company/blog-and-news/displaying-sharepoint-online-2013-lists-to-parent-or-sub-sites)

Comment: @Stish the link seems very interesting , but do you know what will be the differences between using this appoach and using the approaches mentioned on the other reply  mainly using web parts ?

Comment: Above answer is suggesting to use Search Web where result source will the lists from subsite. In this approach you will be add it as web part

Comment: maybe i did not explain my question well. what i was trying to do , is to build a dash board which show for example all the pending items inside a list named "issues" inside all the subsites. but in your approach i will have separate list for each subsite in the dash board, but what i am trying to achieve is to have a single list that have all the pending items from all the subsites . as in my case all the subsites were created from the same site template. so i want inside the dash board to have a list that shows all the pending items inside a lsit named "issues" from all the subsites..